# Ionic button showing 'ion-button' is not a known element

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to ionic, it seems like a silly question but I need some help
Using some simple button is throwing error. I am using ionic 4.0.

> 'ion-button' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ion-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ion-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

```
<ion-button color="primary">Primary</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this,

```
<button ion-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked.
I tried the docs provide in official link but somehow it did't worked. https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/button/#usage
This path also provides the docs, 
node_modules/ionic-angular/components/button/button.js

Comment: All UI components documentation is available here https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/

Comment: You're simply not using Ionic 4 but still version 3 ;)

Comment: How would I use ionic 4? What do I need to change. I have same problem as the OP.

Answer (score 34):

I think the solution is importing Ionic module in the respective module imports

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';  <--add this line
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule, <-- add this line
  ],

})
```

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic then install ionic cli again properly with "-g"

Comment: When I do this, I get a different error: Declaration expected.ts(1146)

Comment: In my case, I am using a standalone component. Hence, imported IonFab in @Component decorator and error was resolved.

Answer (score 26):

In order to avoid that error message:

1. Import **CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA** into app.modules.ts:

```
    import { ErrorHandler, NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

2. Add **schema: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]** to app.modules.ts as below:

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MomentModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
      ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
```

Comment: I think the other important thing to highlight is for people using lazy loading, you have to do this with each page's module.

Comment: this didn't work for me. I also put that in all modules, since I am using lazy loading.

Comment: You should NEVER use "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA", what it does is just telling angular to not complain about components it cannot identify

Comment: Since this is a question related to ionic and not angular, I agree with @cuddlemeister.
You should use IonicModule instead.

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this too. Your solution is not the best one as the new Ionic 4 way is to use `<ion-button>` (https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/components/#button).

It does work for me fine in a page I have under `/src/app/my-page/my-page.html`, but when I put it in `/src/shared/components/my-comp/my-comp.html` it gives the error.  The odd thing is that I have other Ionic elements in the same page `<ion-grid>`, `<ion-row>` and `<ion-col>`. Also, this code used to be in `my-page.html` where it worked without error.

FYI, `MyComponent` is in `components.module.ts` as a `declaration` and an `export`.  Not sure yet what I am missing...

UPDATE 1: Neither moving the `components` directory under `src` nor under `src/app` made any difference.

UPDATE 2: This is my environment:

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.0.6
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.2
   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.2
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.2
   @angular/cli               : 6.1.2
   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.0
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.1
```

UPDATE 3: Still broken in this environment:

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.1.0
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.3
   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.2
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.2
   @angular/cli               : 6.1.2
   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.6
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.5
```

UPDATE 4: After much trial and error, I had to add `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` to my `components.module.ts` file.  I was able to leave the directory structure as-is.  I'm not sure why this is required for this scenario, though.

Comment: CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA allows Angular to incorporate custom elements. https://angular.io/api/core/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA

Comment: I've got similar problem for ionic 4. I have to add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to both app.module.ts and components.module.ts in order to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are not importing the `ionicModule` in the component module. So, Import the `IonicModule`in the module.ts, rest of the things will work fine

Answer (score 4):

Import your custom component in the parent module. for example in your app.module.ts:

```
declarations: [MyComponent],
exports: [
    PopoverComponent,
]
```

Comment: Any Idea why this works, please?

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem in a library that I was building
because I forgot to export the module of that was importing the `IonicModule` and exporting my component.

So, in my module was importing Ionic lib and exporting my component as below.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MyComponent,
  ],
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

And in the `public-api.ts` file of my lib, I should have something like this

```
export { MyModule } from './lib/my.module'; // <--- exporting my module
export { MyComponent } from './lib/my.component';
```

Answer (score 1):

yes try this

```
<button ion-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked.
I tried the docs provide in official link but somehow it did't worked. https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/button/#usage
This path also provides the docs, 
node_modules/ionic-angular/components/button/button.js

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 5, I have a same problem when I build with --prod option.

Since *.module.ts file is not available in components in Ionic 5, I need to add shared module for components and then add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA schema to that shared module.

```
ionic g module modules/shared
```

cat shared.module

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FooComponent } from '../../components/foo/foocomponent.component'; <== Add your components


@NgModule({
  declarations: [FooComponent], <== Add your components
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ], 
  exports: [FooComponent], <== Add your components
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that there were errors prior to this error that seemed to cascade down.  The error I had was some elements in the declarations that should have been in the providers.  Also, one of these was marked private in the constructor when it should have been public.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: DevicesPage }]),
        DevicesPageRoutingModule,
        TranslateModule.forChild()
    ],
    declarations: [DevicesPage  --> remove BLE, LocationAccuracy, DeviceManagerService  ],
    providers: [BLE, LocationAccuracy, DeviceManagerService]  <--Add
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I was stuck on this for a little while as well until I realized that the problem was I did not create the Ionic Angular project properly. you have to include --type=angular

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli

exp:
ionic start myApp tabs --type=angular

Answer (score -1):

I faced similar issue after ionic 4, So I added the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in  app.modules.ts. Then it worked fine

**app.module.ts**

```
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    SpineRestServiceProvider,
    FingerprintAIO
      ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

Answer (score -1):

Should add in app.module.ts

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';


  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] ==> add line**
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, since [Stack Overflow is an English language site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)