# 'ion-option' is not a known element

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm dabbling in Ionic for the first time, learning from the beginning using the components documentation, and I got stuck with this error: 
    Template parse errors:
    'ion-option' is not a known element:

When using a select component in this way:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming">
 <ion-option value="nes">NES</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

I have searched and found solutions like this: [Ionic button showing 'ion-button' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544863/ionic-button-showing-ion-button-is-not-a-known-element)
however, using something like `<option ion-option value="nes">NES</option>` doesn't work. 
Even, I include the `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` line in my module, but no options are showed. 
I'm using:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.5.0 
Ionic Framework   : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.16
```

I'll be grateful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Hair Color</ion-label>
  <ion-select value="brown" ok-text="Okay" cancel-text="Dismiss">
    <ion-select-option value="brown">Brown</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="blonde">Blonde</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="black">Black</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="red">Red</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

ionic 4 has changed its syntax.

Comment: thanks, yesterday I realized there were another documentation page for beta version, however, I must say it is not so visible, it was hard to find it. I think I'll go back to version 3.

Comment: you better stick to v3 until v4 is in alpha. tried to switch but its just for trail purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I used below code and got it working.
Ionic 4

```
 <ion-item>
      <ion-select value="brown" ok-text="Okay" cancel-text="Dismiss">
      <ion-select-option value="brown">Brown</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="blonde">Blonde</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="black">Black</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="red">Red</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **'ion-option'** instead of **'ion-select-option'**.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="this.gender">
    <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

It works for me as expected.
Thank You

Comment: I am using an older version of Ionic/Angular. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Remember to use as the documentation suggest, if you're new just follow the examples.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
    <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Also if you need modify or a complex behavior, the Api Docs is your best ally.

- API Select Ionic

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/